# Flutter: make run-time environment variables available to code is not really working, in docker

Tags: flutter, docker, nginx, devops

If you need to configure eg. backend-api via variables / parameters in Flutter, most mention you should use: **--dart-define** / **fromEnvironment**

**Unfortunately** this method **only** works "**locally**" via eg **run** and **build**.

If you are trying to do the same it within Docker / k8s. (see my example below or grap the code from https://github.com/mklarsen/flutter4cicd ) then you will discover the flutter WebApp does **NOT** have any **Environment** variables, and this is despite the fact that the Docker container DOES have the variables.

If you are trying to do it within Docker. see the setup below - then you will find that the flutter WebApp does NOT have any Environment variables, and this is despite the fact that the Dockercontainer DOES have the variables.

***So what to do then?***,
You can choose one of my suggestions below. I would of course like to hear if you have another solution.

**Idea / workarounds:**

1. https://rebar-ahmad.medium.com/env-aware-flutter-apps-in-docker-b899d0deebfd
2. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv#-readme-tab-
3. https://www.sandromaglione.com/techblog/how-to-use-environmental-variables-in-flutter

The above solutions will work / solved the job, but unfortunately not optimal, seen through my DevOps glasses. as I would prefer NOT to persist variables / secrets etc. in the Docker container.

(Of course, I don't know if I'm the only one with that view :-) )

**This is my test code**

Before you start copying/pasting code *Spoiler alert .-) * **IT doesn't work**, the variables is disappeared when you try to access the WebApp via Docker container.

#Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:stable
ARG BACKEND_APIURL
ENV BACKEND_APIURL ${BACKEND_APIURL}
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
```

#nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }    
}
```

#Builds.sh

```
flutter pub get
flutter config --enable-web
flutter build web -t lib/main.dart --release --dart-define BACKEND_APIURL=${BACKEND_APIURL}

docker build . -t flutter4devops 
docker run --env "BACKEND_APIURL=somebackend.com" -p 80:80 flutter4devops
```

**Note**: *you must of course have docker desktop and flutter sdk installed, etc. before you can try this project.*

Grap the project from Github https://github.com/mklarsen/flutter4cicd

Best regards
Martin

Answer (score 0):

**My Idea / work-arounds:**

- https://rebar-ahmad.medium.com/env-aware-flutter-apps-in-docker-b899d0deebfd
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv#-readme-tab-
- https://www.sandromaglione.com/techblog/how-to-use-environmental-variables-in-flutter

The above solutions will work / solved the job, but unfortunately not optimal, seen through my DevOps glasses. as I would prefer NOT to persist variables / secrets etc. in the Docker container.

(Of course, I don't know if I'm the only one with that view :-) )